# How to push config and custom folder from local system to Remote Repository for hybris

Tags: git, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to setup remote repository for hybris, I have setup a website in the local system.
Now I have to push only config, custom folder to the remote repository, I have created .ignoregit file also but the code is not getting committed after creating a repository.
It shows nothing to commit

Comment: add your `.ignoregit` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create repository at root folder, let's assume `hybris` is your root folder
- Extract your hybris platform source inside `hybris` in such way so your folder path will be `hybris/bin/platform/`
- Replace/Add your config & custom folder
- Now configure your `.gitignore` file(find at root folder) to block everything except config & custom
- Commit changes & push your repository

Sample
**.gitignore**

```
# Folders to ignore at root(hybris)
hybris/log/


# Allow only custom extension
hybris/bin/*
!hybris/bin/custom/

# Absolute path to ignore
hybris/config/fileDontCommit.txt

#  Skip Addon folders from custom storefront
**/_ui/addons
**/_ui-src/addons
**/views/addons
**/tld/addons
**/tags/addons
**/messages/addons
**/addonsrc

# Skip generated classes from custom
Generated*.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a `.gitignore` file specific for hybris:

https://github.com/sap-commerce-tools/supportportal-example/blob/master/.gitignore

In your case you have to remove / comment line 14, as you want to commit `hybris/config` to your repository if I understood you correctly.

Also check out my gradle plugin for hybris development.
The plugin and examples can be found here:
https://github.com/sap-commerce-tools